# jQuery accordions, allowing one open at once only

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a custom jQuery accordion set I have created - but having some issues with making it work so that only one accordion is allowed to be open at once - so, at the start all are closed, then when the user opens one, if they click to open another, the one that is open should close, and the selected one open. Then it should only allow the selected one to be in view at once at all times... Any help available on this? Code is below:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Accordion -- ONE -->
<div class="accordionParent">
<div class="fullWidthWrapper accordionWrapper accordionPink">
<div class="container">
<div class="accordionPencil"><a class="accordionTrigger"><h3>ONE</h3></a></div>
<div class="closeAccordionWrapper"><img src="assets/images/about/accordionX.png" width="120" class="accordionBtn"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="fullWidthWrapper accordionContent">
<div class="container">
<p>CONTENT HERE...</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end of Accordion -- ONE -->

<!-- Accordion -- TWO -->
<div class="accordionParent">
<div class="fullWidthWrapper accordionWrapper accordionBlue">
<div class="container">
<div class="accordionPencil"><a class="accordionTrigger"><h3>TWO</h3></a></div>
<div class="closeAccordionWrapper"><img src="assets/images/about/accordionX.png" width="120" class="accordionBtn"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="fullWidthWrapper accordionContent">
<div class="container">
<p>CONTENT HERE...</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end of Accordion -- TWO -->



<!-- Accordion -- THREE -->
<div class="accordionParent">
<div class="fullWidthWrapper accordionWrapper accordionPink">
<div class="container">
<div class="accordionPencil"><a class="accordionTrigger"><h3>THREE</h3></a></div>
<div class="closeAccordionWrapper"><img src="assets/images/about/accordionX.png" width="120" class="accordionBtn"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="fullWidthWrapper accordionContent">
<div class="container">
<p>CONTENT HERE...</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end of Accordion -- THREE -->
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var accordionInView = 0

$(".accordionWrapper").click(function(){

    if (accordionInView == 0) {

    accordionInView = 1;
    $(this).find(".accordionBtn").toggleClass("rotated");
    $(this).closest('.accordionParent').find(".accordionContent").css('opacity', 0).slideDown('slow').animate({ opacity: 1 },{ queue: false, duration: 'slow' });

    }

    else if (accordionInView == 1) {

    accordionInView = 0;
    $(this).find(".accordionBtn").toggleClass("rotated");
    $(this).closest('.accordionParent').find(".accordionContent").css('opacity', 1).slideUp('slow').animate({ opacity: 0 },{ queue: false, duration: 'slow' });
    }


});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify things a bit: (you don't need a flag)

```
   $(".accordionWrapper").click(function() {

   if ($(this).closest('.accordionParent').find(".accordionContent").is(':visible')) {
     $(this).find(".accordionBtn").toggleClass("rotated");
     $(this).closest('.accordionParent').find(".accordionContent").slideUp('slow');

   } else {
     $(this).find(".accordionBtn").toggleClass("rotated");
     $(this).closest('.accordionParent').find(".accordionContent").slideDown('slow');
     $(this).closest('.accordionParent').siblings('.accordionParent').find(".accordionContent").slideUp('slow');
   }

 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8L5kkss2/

So, check if content is visible, if so -> hide, if is invisible -> show, and hide the rest of accordions content (last line is crucial here - it will close opened content of other sections).

P.S. you can return your desired animation, i simplified it for demo purposes.

Comment: Thanks works 90%... last bit is that the accordionbtn rotations need to work as well...

Comment: Great! Glad to help. ;)